# WCF client can still connect after deleting service's certificate

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I've got a WCF client and service. The service is configured to use a certificate for encryption. This is all working fine. We're using self-signed certificates for testing.

Except that one of my QA guys has deleted the certificate from his client PC and he can still connect to the service.

I've looked in CERTMGR.MSC and I can't see any sign of the certificate anywhere on the client PC, either in his account or in Local Machine.

What am I missing? Where else should I look?

Comment: Look in the app.config file and in the localmachine store aswell.

Comment: What am I looking for in the app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

We were looking in the wrong config file. He'd set certificateValidationMode="None". Bah.

Comment: ...but someone should feel free to post a more complete list of places to look and things to look for...